# What Root-finding algorithm for derivative of function?

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

**The problem**

We have the equation:

$\frac{d\alpha}{du} = \frac{R - a cos(u)}{\sqrt{b^2 +(a cos(u))^2}}$
$ \frac{d\xi}{du} = R cos \alpha$
$\frac{d\eta}{du} = R sin \alpha$

$\xi$ and $\eta$ are the curves $x$ and $y$ coordinate when then the parameter $u$ is between $0$ and $2\pi$.

We are also given the following $\{\alpha(2\pi) = \frac{\pi}{2}, R = 8.8, a = 12\}$. How do we find $b$ in $\frac{d\alpha}{du}$? Hint: use numerical approach

**My attempts**
I tried looking into numerical root-finding algorithms newton-rhapson, but the problem is we are not given  the alpha function $\alpha$ and trying to find $b$ using only $\frac{d\alpha}{du}$ does not work because the derivative to it is $0$. I also attempted using bisection method, again this failed because the we only have the function for $\frac{d\alpha}{du}$. Here are the algorithms using numpy.

```
# Newton
R = 8.8
a = 12
u = 2*np.pi
i = 0
b = 0
t = 1
while np.absolute(t) > 5e-5:
    f = ((R - a * np.cos(np.pi)) / 
         np.sqrt(b**2 + (a * np.cos (u))**2)) - np.pi/2
    fp = (a*(b**2)*np.sin(u)/
          ((a**2) * ((np.cos(u))**2) + b**2)**(3/2))
    g=t
    t=f/fp
    quad = t/g**2 
    lin = t/g
    i+=1
    b = b - t
root = b

# Bisection method
R = 8.8
a = 12
u = 2*np.pi

i = 0
b0 = 30
b1 = 40

while np.absolute(b1-b0) > 5e-5:
    f0 = ((R - a * np.cos(np.pi))/
         (np.sqrt(b0**2 + 
                 (a * np.cos(u))**2))) - np.pi/2
    f1 = ((R - a * np.cos(np.pi))/
         (np.sqrt(b1**2 + 
                 (a * np.cos(u))**2))) - np.pi/2
    t = f1*(x1-x0) / (f1 - f0)
    b0 = b1
    b1 = b1 - t
    i += 1
root = b1
```

Comment: the integral of $\alpha(u)=\frac{8.8\, -12 \cos (u)}{\sqrt{b^2+144 \cos ^2(u)}}$ is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$
I found the value of $b=34.185$ with other methods (not numerical)
Hope this helps

Comment: Do you mind if I ask how you approached this problem?

Comment: I solved the definite integral between 0 and $2\pi$ with the help of Mathematica. Knowing that this was $\frac{\pi}{2}$ I plotted it as a  function of $b$ and then I found the zero. It's an unorthodox approach :)

Comment: Interesting! This might help, Thanks :)